# How to send multiple queries to Prometheus HTTP API?

Tags: prometheus

This is a Prometheus HTTP API GET call for one query, i.e, "up".

```
http://localhost:port/api/v1/query?query=up[1m]
```

Now, if I want to send multiple queries (not only "up", but other queries as well), what will be the syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hack your way around it as long as you're not too picky about what you want to query. E.g. if you want to query all `up` time series and all `cpu_utilization` time series, you can use something like this:

```
{__name__=~"up|cpu_utilization"}
```

It will even work with range queries, as long as you want the same range for all time series:

```
{__name__=~"up|cpu_utilization"}[1m]
```

But not if you want different time ranges or want to add selectors (e.g. there's no easy way of combining `up{job="prometheus}` and `cpu_utilization{instance="foo:8080"}`).

Answer (score 0):

You can't send multiple queries as `query= qry1 qry2..` in a single HTTP API call. If you take a closer look to the response object:

```sh
$ curl 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query?query=up&time=2015-07-01T20:10:51.781Z'
{
   "status" : "success",
   "data" : {
      "resultType" : "vector",
      "result" : [
         {
            "metric" : {
               "__name__" : "up",
               "job" : "prometheus",
               "instance" : "localhost:9090"
            },
            "value": [ 1435781451.781, "1" ]
         },
         {
            "metric" : {
               "__name__" : "up",
               "job" : "node",
               "instance" : "localhost:9100"
            },
            "value" : [ 1435781451.781, "0" ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

You will see that `"data"` field contains only two keys (i.e. `"resultType"` and `"result"`) and it isn't an array itself. So there is no chance that `"data"` will hold the result of multiple queries.